# AsyncTask concurrency issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am using Asynctask to do network operation .i am using third party library to fetch data from my database.

Problem
i am hitting query in doInBackgroun method of my asynctask that eventually call a callback method which has result to display.But onPostExecute method get called before the callback method call itslef .Hence data is never attached to adapter which i set in onPostExecute.

Issue:how to wait doInbackground method to return until the callbackmethod get called.So that i can call onPostExecute method after data get available.

below is my asyntTask and call back method is onCompleted.

in my onPostExecute i am using data to display it in adapter.so i havent fully posted it because it is bunch of code.

```
public class MyReviewLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<WYF_User_Items>>
    {
        ProgressDialog pdilog;
        List<WYF_User_Items> result_to_send_to_adapter;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdilog=new ProgressDialog(SingleReviewActivity.this);
            pdilog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pdilog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pdilog.setMessage("please wait");
            pdilog.setTitle("Review Details");
            pdilog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected List<WYF_User_Items> doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getDatabaseTable();

            MobileServiceQuery<WYF_User_Items> query=new MobileServiceQuery<WYF_User_Items>();
            query.select("review_rating","review_body","unique_user_id","userName");
            wyf_user_item_table.where().field("brand_name").eq(review_name).execute(new TableQueryCallback<WYF_User_Items>() {

                @Override
                 public void  onCompleted(List<WYF_User_Items> result, int arg1,
                        Exception arg2, ServiceFilterResponse arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i(TAG, "size is "+result.size());
                    result_to_send_to_adapter=result;
                    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "unique user id of all user who has entered review is "+result.get(i).getUnique_user_id()+" and their names are "+result.get(i).getUserName());

                    }

                }
            });


            wyf_user_item_table.select("review_rating").add(new MobileServiceQuery<WYF_User_Items>());
            return result_to_send_to_adapter;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<WYF_User_Items> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute called");
            pdilog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Can we see your AsyncTask code?

Comment: It looks like your third party code also uses a separate thread because it return right away inside your doInBackground thread thus finishing do in background and going onto post execute

Comment: @Raigex:yes , it is working same.

Comment: @kaushaltrivedi: if the third party is using a seperate thread why do you need to use an AsyncTask, just do the logic you need inside the callback.

Comment: @Raigex:i can't do that because it is fetching thousands of rows from database end hence i am using traditional asynctask so that UI thread do not get blocked,Still i haven't checked that if it is using different thread to do network operation or not.i will check it and ping you asap.thanx for suggestion.but i am also looking for other options.

Comment: Also please tell us which third party library you are using so we might be able to advice some more. It really looks like your third party library uses a separate thread to run network requests, if so the callback will also be on another thread. and if that is true then your AsyncTask is redundant as most of the updates to the UI will need to be run on the UI thread.

Comment: How are you executing MyReviewLoadingTask?

Answer (score 0):

You do need an `AsyncTask` for this usecase imo. If the `MobileQueryService` runs on a different `Thread` already, just implement your logic on the callback `onCompleted` provided.